# phone field in Custom user model fills with first_name and last_name after registration in Django

Tags: python, django

Im trying to make signup view for my app and after i fill form user saves, but phone field fills with first name + second name. It validates phone correctly but then fills phone field in db with nonsense.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.urls import reverse

from .managers import CustomUserManager


class AvitoUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(_("phone number"), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "phone"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def get_username(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:profile', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

    def __str__(self):
        return f'AvitoUser№ {self.id} , f-s name: {self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


AvitoUser = get_user_model()

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First name', max_length=16)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last name', max_length=16)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()


    class Meta:
        model = AvitoUser
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "phone",  "password1", "password2",]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from . import forms

AvitoUser = get_user_model()

...

class SignupView(generic.CreateView):
    model = AvitoUser
    form_class = forms.RegisterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
    template_name = "registration/signup.html"


...
```

**registration/signup.html**

```
{% extends 'base_generic.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**managers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where phone is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self,first_name, second_name, phone, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given phone and password.
        """
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError(_("The phone must be set"))
        user = self.model(first_name=first_name, second_name=second_name, phone=phone, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

example:
When i register i input this:
[register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W91RB.jpg)
and get this
[how it looks in bd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0bHd.jpg)

It works fine when i use AvitoUser.objects.create_user("Hello", "World", "79531323301", "somepassword")
How do i fill phone field with phone?

same result when i use function instead of class in **views.py** :

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = forms.RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password2'])
            new_user.save()
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('users:profile', kwargs={'pk': new_user.id}))
    else:
        user_form = forms.RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': user_form})
```

Answer (score 0):

changed get_username method in models.py for AvitoUser and looks like it works